# AutoSpInstaller warning during SP2013 Install

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services, autospinstaller

I am installing a SP2013 Dev instance. I have SQL 2012 and SP2013 on the same machine. I don't have reporting services installed but I did add the SharePoint reports service option during SQL installation.

During AutoSpInstaller installation I am getting this warning:

```
WARNING: Feature PowerView\Feature.xml had failed to install for the following reason: Failed to create receiver object from assembly "Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.UI.ServerPages,Version=11.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91", class "Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.UI.PowerViewSiteFeature" for feature "PowerView" (ID: bf8b58f5-ebae-4a70-9848-622beaaf2043).: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition.get_ReceiverObject().
WARNING: Feature ReportServer\Feature.xml had failed to install for the following reason: Failed to create receiver object from assembly "Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.UI.ServerPages,Version=11.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91", class "Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.UI.ReportServerFeature" for feature "ReportServer" (ID: e8389ec7-70fd-4179-a1c4-6fcb4342d7a0).: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition.get_ReceiverObject().
WARNING: Feature ReportServer\Feature.xml had failed to install for the following reason: Failed to create receiver object from assembly "Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.UI.ServerPages,Version=11.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91", class "Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.UI.ReportServerFeature" for feature "ReportServer" (ID: e8389ec7-70fd-4179-a1c4-6fcb4342d7a0).: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition.get_ReceiverObject().
```

Comment: In which section of AutoSPInstaller did you get the warning?

Comment: I get this warning right after the config database is created. It can't find a related section in the input file where something is done with PowerView

Comment: I've never installed a DEV-VM with SharePoint integrated Reports on the same box. Might be a problematic combination. Do you need Reports?

Comment: No I don't need it. I am now trying to install without the SharePoint reporting server.

Comment: Installing when no reporting server for SharePoint is installed the error doesn't appear. So it seems you can not host on same server

Comment: Added this as answer for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An AutoSPInstaller-Installation with installed Reporting-Services in SharePoint Integrated Mode seems to be a problematic combination if everything is installed on one machine.